# stuck on 'loading' Tumblr in my app store

Tags: applications, ios-appstore

[image]

I tried to download Tumblr and it got stuck on the 'loading' part in the app store and I've tried everything I can think blr

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, have you tried restarting?

If so, you can delete the app while it is downloading and then re-download it from the store. To do this:

Settings > General > Storage & iCloud Usage > Manage Storage > Tumblr > Delete App

I would advise a restart before trying to re-download the app.